# Is it possible to know whether the following series converges without its formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given this series: 
$$\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{6} + \dfrac{1}{10} + \dfrac{1}{14} + \dfrac{1}{18} + \ldots$$
Is it possible to know if the series converges without its formula? I tried using the comparison test with both $1/n$ and $1/n^2$ but these don't yield results. The formula for this series is $1/[2(2n+1)]$, which I can use in other convergence tests, but if I didn't know that or couldn't find it, is it still possible to determine convergence without the formula?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't have the formula, how would you _know_ that the next term after $\frac1{18}$ is actually $\frac1{22}$? Also, you made a typo in the formula, it's likely supposed to be a $4$, not $2$.

Comment: How would you possibly *define* $n^{\rm th}$ term of sequesnce, without knowing it's formula?

Comment: Instead of the comparison test you should use the *limit comparison test*.

Comment: Yes, my apologies. That formula should be 1/(2*(2n-1)). This was just a question we were given in my class. We were only given an ellipsis to signal the series continues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is pretty easy as the denominators are in arithmetic sequence with common difference equal to four, so:

$$a_1=2\;,\;\;d=4\implies a_n=a_1+(n-1)d=2+4(n-1)=4n-2$$

and thus your series is simply

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{4n-2}$$

Now it is very simple to show the series is divergent.

Comment: Thanks! I knew the denominator looked like an arithmetic sequence, but I didn't know to deduce the formula from that.

Comment: @user528378 Don't worry, it takes some time to assimilate this stuff and be able to deduce things by yourself. The most important thing is to understand basically what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{6} + \dfrac{1}{10} + \dfrac{1}{14} + \dfrac{1}{18} + \ldots > \\ 
\dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{1}{8} + \dfrac{1}{12} + \dfrac{1}{16} + \dfrac{1}{20} + \ldots = \\
\dfrac{1}{4}\left(\dfrac{1}{1} + \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{3} + \dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{1}{5} + \ldots \right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $n\ge 1,$   integer.

$a_n = \dfrac{1}{2+(n-1)4} \gt $

$\dfrac{1}{4+4(n-1)} = \dfrac{1}{4n}$,

in essence the harmonic series, divergent.